# Implementing MVC architecture in an android application

Tags: android, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I wanna implement **MVC** architecture for an **Android application**. Is it possible to do so. Or is it implemented by default.

Answer (score 2):

It's not implemented by default but somehow it helps to follow the guideline from the android development site tutorials like : (http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html)

Comment: A more concrete example : (http://androidexample.com/Use_MVC_Pattern_To_Create_Very_Basic_Shopping_Cart__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=116&aaid=138)

Comment: Also, a more helpful one : (http://www.emirweb.com/AndroidTutorial.php)

Comment: Second one is actually less helpful one - it basically describes android java framework. First one is realy helpfull since it actually describe how to "create" MVC on top of android java framework (or API - whetever name you prefer).